# .htaccess php redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

for some reason when i put a ".php" after the filename it works, and loads perfectly in the "facebox" form. But check this out.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/([0-9]+).*/?$ media/report.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

my PHP code:

```
<a style="float: right;padding-right: 15px;" href="media/report/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" rel="facebox"><img src="_lib/images/notice.png"></a>
```

if want to see a live viewing, check out http://www.krissales.me/#/media/39.Article-Testing

and hit the report icon image in the article comments. For some reason, it loads the facebox, but it just doesn't load the form handler.

However it works perfectly if I were to add a .php after report along with the tags for the ID, and take off the .htaccess. But I'm trying to clean up the URLS.

Would you happen to know what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why is there a `#` in your URL? If I remove that I seem to get your test output. Firefox appear to send it in the request, but I wouldn't count on all browsers doing that seeing as it denotes an anchor and doesn't really need to be sent. Upon closer inspection, your RewriteRule also doesn't account for the `#`.

Comment: so what? am I suppose to add the # symbol in the rewrite rule?

Comment: The rewrite rule *can't* account for the `#`.  It, and everything after it, is a *fragment identifier*, and no browser i know of includes it in the request.  I'm pretty sure it wouldn't even be RFC-compliant to do so.  To the server that URL looks like `/`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/report/([0-9]+)(/)?$ media/report.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `[0-9]+` part stands for *one digit or more*, the braces `()` return the matched value to a variable, `$1` in your case.

**UPDATE** As stated above, everything after `#` is the Javascript business. The Apache web server handles everything before the `#` sign.

Comment: nah, didn't work. You think it has something to do with the core.js file? I do use a hash tag type platform.

Comment: Did you try to navigate to the page directly?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^#/media/([0-9]+).*/?$ media/report.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Because of your weird hashmark stuff.

It could also be simplified to:

```
RewriteRule ^#/media/([0-9]+).*$ media/report.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Since you don't appear to care about anything following the id number.

Comment: Good luck getting the server to even *see* a hash-URL.  Those only work client-side; the browser strips off the hash mark (and everything after) when sending the GET request to the server.

Comment: @cHao Firefox doesn't strip. I checked the request myself. It probably *should* and I'd wager that other browsers *will*. There's also probably a pisspile of JS behind this site to do god-knows-what so we don't really know what requests apache is receiving anyway.

Comment: "...the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme."  (RFC3986, §3.5)   So yeah, it *definitely* should be stripping them.